# Prove that any cardinal has a successor without using ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Can one show that any cardinal has a successor without using ordinals? I mean: cardinals are not defined as special ordinals, but have a naive definition, as equivalence classes of equipotent sets, and ordinals are not used in the proof. If you don't like that, this is another formulation: how does one prove the theorem "Let A be a set. There exists a set B such that
(i) card B > card A
(ii) for every set C such that card C > card A, one has card C ≥ card B."

Of course, the Axiom of Choice is required throughout.

Comment: First prove that $\mathscr P (\kappa)$ is strictly larger than $\kappa$.  Then, working within $\mathscr P(\kappa \times \kappa)$ and using Choice, construct a set $S$ consisting of a single representative of each well ordering of $\kappa$.  Prove that $\vert S \vert$ satisfies the conditions you want.

Comment: What formulation of set theory are you working in?  Equivalence classes of equipotent sets are proper classes and hence don't exist as objects in ZF.

Comment: @RobertShore: I don't understand your comment: what is a representative of a well ordering?

Comment: @RobArthan All possible relations on $\kappa$ are contained within $\mathscr P (\kappa \times \kappa)$.  Some of those relations are well orderings.  Some of the relations that are well orderings are order-isomorphic to one another.  Carve out a subset of $\mathscr P (\mathscr P (\kappa \times \kappa))$ consisting of all well orderings.  Define an equivalence relation on that subset -- two such elements of the subset are equivalent if they are order-isomorphic.  Choose one element from each equivalence class.

Comment: @Robert Shore. Suppose $\kappa = \aleph_0$. Your $S$ is in bijection with the set of denumerable ordinals. Then you have to prove i) that this set is not denumerable ; ii) that any nondenumerable set contains a set with the sama cardinality as $S$. Not so easy.

Comment: @abellaic The key is that you can well-order the equivalence classes according to which embeds as an initial segment of the other. This well ordering will be strictly longer than any countable well-ordering, and is the shortest such, so embeds into any uncountable well-ordering.

Comment: What do you think of the following? According to Chaim Samuel Hönig in his paper “Proof of the well-ordering of cardinal numbers,” _Proc. Amer. Math. Soc._ 5 (1954), 312, every set of cardinals contains a minimal element. So you have onky to apply this result to the (non-empty) set of cardinals which are > $\kappa$ et ≤ $2^\kappa$ to get a successor for $\kappa$.

Maybe this paper is false, as it has very few citations?

Comment: @abellaic That proof looks fine, and perhaps could be said to eliminate the use of well-orderings in general as opposed to just ordinals. On the other hand, it would be more accurate to say it hides the use of transfinite induction in Zorn's lemma. Furthermore, the main idea can be expressed more succinctly with well-orderings: for each $i,$ choose a well-ordering of $A_i.$ Say the well-ordering chosen for $A_{i_0}$ has the minimal length... then $A_{i_0}$ injects into each $A_i.$ (If you follow how the machinery of Zorn's lemma gives the maximal set in the proof, you'll see it's just this.)

Comment: @abellaic (Well, the Zorn's lemma way constructs the well-orderings, or at least constructs them in parallel, up to the point that one of the sets is exhausted, rather than them being chosen at the beginning, but the idea is pretty much the same.)